# findOrFail() in Query\Builder

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, query-builder

```
DB::table('amounts')->findOrFail($id);
```

return

> **Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::findOrFail()**

I don't want to use models here.

What's the best way to achieve this ? (I just want to return a `404` when the id is not in the table.)

---

In the meantime I do:

```
$amount = DB::table('amounts')->find($request->input('amount'));
if(!$amount) abort(404);
```

Comment: If you do not want use Models, your second variant is normal.

Comment: Do you know if is there a reason that findOrFail is not implement ?

Comment: I think, because Query Builder is only the wrapper for sql language. Eloquent model is a combination from query builder and some logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this API documentation

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_find

https://laravel.com/api/5.4/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Builder.html#method_findOrFail

`find($id)` is **Database Builder** method but `findOrFail($id)` is not so you cannot use it directly that way.

I didn't really get why you don't want to use **Eloquent Model** but thats the good way to do or stick with what you are doing in meantime.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to use models then that will do the job. If you use models you can `try` and `catch` the

> \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\ModelNotFoundException

and abort `404` at that point.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with below code to get record if exits into table or not:

```
$result = DB::table('amounts')->find($id);

if($result == NULL) //check if no record found
{
        //do your stuff here
}
else //if record found from table
{
        //do your stuff here
}
```

Hope this helps.